# How to substring (variable name) from "int a, b, c = 0, d;"

Tags: java

I have my code to search string "int" in text file and substring (variable name) from it, but I have some problem about substring (variable name)

> > like "int a, b, c = 0, d;"

I want my output is:

- Variable name is: a
- Variable name is: b
- Variable name is: c
- Variable name is: d

Can i modify my code?

This is my code.

```
                //print variable name and position
                int k4 = line.indexOf("=",k+1);
                int k5 = line.indexOf(";", k+1);
                int k6 = line.indexOf(",", k+1);
                int cTemp1 = 0;

                //Count whitespace before variable name, print variable name and length of variable name
                if (k4 != -1){
                    String temp4 = line.substring(k+3, k4);     //Substring variable name
                    if(k4 != -1){
                        int varName = line.indexOf(temp4.trim(), k+3);
                        String total_length = line.substring(k+3, varName);     
                        int wPattern = total_length.length();       
                        System.out.println("  - Whitespace before variable name \"" + temp4.trim() + "\" are: ," + wPattern);
                    }
                    System.out.println("  - Variable name type INTEGER at line: " + lineNumber + " is: "+temp4.trim());
                    System.out.print("  - Length of variable name \"" + temp4.trim() + "\" is: ," + temp4.trim().length() + "\n\n");
                    varLength_Integer1 += temp4.trim().length();
                }
                else if(k5 != -1){
                    String temp5 = line.substring(k+4, k5);
                    System.out.println("  - Variable name type INTEGER at line: " + lineNumber + " is: "+temp5.trim());
                    System.out.print("  - Length of variable name \"" + temp5.trim() + "\" is: ," + temp5.trim().length() + "\n\n");
                    varLength_Integer2 += temp5.trim().length();
                }
                else if(k6 != -1){
                    String temp6 = line.substring(k+4, k6);
                    System.out.println("  - Variable name type INTEGER at line: " + lineNumber + " is: "+temp6.trim());
                    System.out.print("  - Length of variable name \"" + temp6.trim() + "\" is: ," + temp6.trim().length() + "\n\n");
                    varLength_Integer3 += temp6.trim().length();
                }
                avgInteger += (varLength_Integer1 + varLength_Integer2 + varLength_Integer3)/(double)c3;
                //END Count whitespace before variable name, print variable name and length of variable name

            }
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like doing this with a regex

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ParseInt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test =  "int a, b, c = 0, d;\n\nint e, b, c = 0, d";

        String pattern = "int(.*)";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        String patternVar = "([A-Za-z][a-zA-Z_0-9]*)(\\[\\])?";
        Pattern rVar = Pattern.compile(patternVar);

        String[] linesNewline = test.split("\n");

        for (int nLI=0;nLI < linesNewline.length; ++nLI) {
            String[] lines = linesNewline[nLI].split(";");
            for (int i=0;i < lines.length; ++i) {
                Matcher m = r.matcher(lines[i]);
                if (m.find()) {
                    String[] variables = m.group(1).split(",");
                    for (int ii=0; ii < variables.length; ++ii) {
                        Matcher mVar = rVar.matcher(variables[ii].trim());
                        if (mVar.find()) {
                            System.out.println("Variable is " + mVar.group(1));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The output is for the input string "int a, b, c = 0, d;\n\nint e, b, c = 0, d"

```
Variable is a
Variable is b
Variable is c
Variable is d
Variable is e
Variable is b
Variable is c
Variable is d
```

The output is for the input string "int a, a1, b, b1;"

```
Variable is a
Variable is a1
Variable is b
Variable is b1
```

The output is for the input string "int d[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };"

```
Variable is d
```

The output is for the input string "int d0 = sc.nextInt(); int d1 = sc.nextInt(); int d2 = sc.nextInt();"

```
Variable is d0
Variable is d1
Variable is d2
```

Comment: Yeah, Its work but if 
"int a, a1, b, b1;"

I will  add 0-9 in "String patternVar = "([A-Za-z_]*)";" line right?

and if input like this

"int d[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };"

out put is 
- Variable is 28
- Variable is 31
- Variable is 30
- Variable is 31
- Variable is 30
- Variable is 31
- Variable is 31
- Variable is 30
- Variable is 31
- Variable is 30
- Variable is 31

But, I want only "d".

How can i modify your code?

Thank you very much.

Comment: @Anonymous wait just updating my code in a minutes it should normally be patternVar=([A-Za-z_]*)([])?" but testing it

Comment: @Anonymous Ok Update my code that the 2 other case works now to

Comment: Thank you Kordi's, but I have some question.

if code declare "int d0 = sc.nextInt(); int d1 = sc.nextInt(); int d2 = sc.nextInt();" in one line.

How can i detect variable name?
Thank you very much for your answering.

Comment: would just `line.split(";");` before putting into the pattern match

Comment: What is the idea with `pattern = "int(.*)";` and its use? This will remove all occurrences of `int`, plus any and all next characters, right? So a variable `myint1` will get destroyed. As long as you are using a regex, safer to use something like `^int\\s+` instead (assuming `\\s` eats all whitespace, as usual).

Comment: @RadLexus no. cause its int myInt so myint1 will not be destroyed. `int myInt1, myInt2 = 3`will out put `Variable is myInt1\nVariable is myInt2`. int(.*) means match all with int and put all other in the first group.

Answer (score 0):

You can try -

```
String inputTxt = "int aa, b, c = 0, d=89;";
inputTxt = inputTxt .replaceAll("int ", "")
                    .replaceAll(";", ",")
                    .replaceAll("=.\\d,", ",");
String[] varNames = inputTxt.split(",");

for (String var : varNames) {
    System.out.println(var);
}
```

You can alter the code as per your requirement. But this will give you a better starting point.